# Cross compiling a Qt GUI application on Qt Creator: Incompatible library error

Tags: qt4, arm, qt-creator, cross-compiling, beagleboard

I am trying to compile Qt for Beaglebord (ARM) for a while and run some basic Hello Word GUI application. I have build Qt for cross compile with some errors and warnings mentioned below and configured my Qt Creator to work with my cross compile tool-chain. And I have created a simple Qt GUI project but when I try to build my project I am getting these errors:

```
:-1: error: skipping incompatible /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.7.4-generic/lib/libQtGui.so when searching for -lQtGui
:-1: error: skipping incompatible /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.7.4-generic/lib/libQtGui.so when searching for -lQtGui
:-1: error: cannot find -lQtGui
:-1: error: skipping incompatible /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.7.4-generic/lib/libQtNetwork.so when searching for -lQtNetwork
:-1: error: skipping incompatible /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.7.4-generic/lib/libQtNetwork.so when searching for -lQtNetwork
:-1: error: cannot find -lQtNetwork
:-1: error: skipping incompatible /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.7.4-generic/lib/libQtCore.so when searching for -lQtCore
:-1: error: skipping incompatible /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.7.4-generic/lib/libQtCore.so when searching for -lQtCore
:-1: error: cannot find -lQtCore
:-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Alsa there is a yellow warning icon on list item  Qt Creator->Options->Qt4 Qt Versions list:

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 x86 and latest Angstrom tool-chain. I have used Angstrom online builder to build my tool-chain. I have installed my Qt Creator with lates offline Qt SDK v4.7.4. After that I have downloaded Qt source qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4.zip and configured as below:

Changed qws/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++/qmake.conf as:

```
    #
    # qmake configuration for building with arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
    #

    include(../../common/g++.conf)
    include(../../common/linux.conf)
    include(../../common/qws.conf)

    # modifications to g++.conf
    QMAKE_CC                = /home/olcay/armx86/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc
    QMAKE_CXX               = /home/olcay/armx86/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++
    QMAKE_LINK              = /home/olcay/armx86/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++
    QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB        = /home/olcay/armx86/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++

    # modifications to linux.conf
    QMAKE_AR                = /home/olcay/armx86/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-ar cqs
    QMAKE_OBJCOPY           = /home/olcay/armx86/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-objcopy
    QMAKE_STRIP             = /home/olcay/armx86/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-strip

    load(qt_config)
```

Congigured Qt with following settings:

```
./configure
    -embedded armv7
    -little-endian
    -xplatform qws/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++
    -qt-gfx-linuxfb
    -qt-gfx-vnc
    -largefile
    -no-accessibility
    -no-qt3support
    -no-sse2
    -qt-libpng
    -qt-libjpeg
    -no-cups
    -no-libtiff
    -nowebkit
    -qt-zlib
    -nomake examples
    -nomake demos
    -opensource
    -confirm-license
    -no-fast
    -multimedia
    -optimized-qmake
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/MiwDSwx2) is my console output for configuration script.

As you can see in configure output there is only tree warnings:

```
for /home/olcay/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4/src/3rdparty/webkit/WebKit/qt/tests/hybridPixmap/hybridPixmap.pro
WARNING: Failure to find: hybridPixmap.cpp
for /home/olcay/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4/src/3rdparty/webkit/WebKit/qt/tests/benchmarks/loading/loading.pro
WARNING: Failure to find: loading.cpp
for /home/olcay/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.4/src/3rdparty/webkit/WebKit/qt/tests/benchmarks/painting/painting.pro
WARNING: Failure to find: painting.cpp
```

Also there is a warning about floating point format:

```
    The system floating point format could not be detected.
    This may cause data to be generated in a wrong format
```

Please help me to find out the problem.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

If you have previously read this question I have changed my configuration and recompiled and installed Qt and updated my question based on new configuration and new results. It provide me to get ride of make install errors but main problem still not solved.

**UPDATE 2**

I have noticed that Qt Creator calling **qmake** for **linux-g++-32** not for **qws/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++** so I changed linux-g++-32/qmake.conf with required settings. Now I am able to build my application. But I have not test application binary yet because I am at home now. I will test my application and post the results here tomorrow.